# Why do I get the error "TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' " when I am trying to execute this code?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, typeerror

I am trying to make a guess game program where you have to guess a number between 0-100 on a GUI using `Tkinter`, and it also counts your amount of attempts but I get this error on line 25:

> '<' is not supported between instances of str and int.

What can I do to solve this issue? This code would work on a command line but not when I have attempted to translate it into a GUI. I am also not sure if the code even works.

My updated code so far is:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
#need to count how many attempts you made
window = Tk()

window.title("Number guessing game")

window.geometry('350x200')

lbl = Label(window, text="Enter a number here from 1-100: ")

lbl.grid(column=0,row=0)

guess_var = IntVar(window)

txt = Entry(window, textvariable=guess_var)

txt= Entry(window, width=10)

txt.grid(column=1,row=0)

numguess = 0

secret_num = random.randint(1, 100)

def clicked():
    if guess < 0:
        lbl2.configure(text ="Please enter a sensible number.")
    if guess > 100:
        lbl2.configure(text ="Please enter a sensible number.")
    if guess == secret_num:
        lbl2.configure(text ="You guessed correctly.")
        lbl3.confgure(text=numguess)
    elif guess < secret_num:
        numguess = numguess + 1
        lbl2.configure(text ="higher!")
        lbl = Label(window, text="Enter a number here from 1-100: ")
    else:
        numguess = numguess + 1
        lbl2.configure(text ="lower!")
        lbl = Label(window, text="Enter a number here form 1-100")

lbl2 = Label(window,text = " ")

lbl2.grid(column=1, row=2)

lbl3 = Label(window,text = " ")

lbl3.grid(column=1, row=3)

btn = Button(window, text="Enter", command=clicked)

guess = int(txt.get())

btn.grid(column=3, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to convert `guess = txt.get()` to an integer, i.e. `guess = int(txt.get())` if you are sure that the input will be an integer.

Comment: You should run `guess = txt.get()` inside `clicked()` function, and you need to convert it to integer before those comparisons.  Also you need to cater conversion exception due to invalid content.

Answer (score 2):

```
guess = txt.get()
```

returns a string value. To be able to perform comparisons with integers, you need to convert `guess` from a string to an integer, i.e.:

```
guess = int(txt.get())
```

To be safe, you may want to handle the case where the user inputs something which cannot be converted to a integer; how to do this depends on the design of your problem - you should consider validating the user input.

One way to do this could be by using `IntVar`, e.g.:

```
guess_var = IntVar(window)                                                      
txt = Entry(window, textvariable=guess_var)                                     

txt.grid(column=1,row=0)                                                        

numguess = 0                                                                    

secret_num = random.randint(1, 100)                                             

guess = guess_var.get()
```

Note that if you want to use the `numguess` global variable inside your `clicked` function, you need to declare `global numguess` in your function definition, e.g.:

```
def clicked():                                                                  
    global numguess
```

Comment: Well i remember doing guess = int(txt.get()) but I ended up with "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' So I could try giving IntVar thing a try

Comment: Are you sure that you input an integer, without any spaces etc.?

Comment: `int(txt.get())` is correct. If you're getting "invalid literal" that means you're trying to convert something that can't be converted to an int -- probably an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

> is not supported between instances of str and int.

There are sufficient errors.

Don't use wildcard `from tkinter import *` for Python 3.x

- Comment out on  lines 24 to 27. So it doesn't work that out.
- In line 23, Add `global numguess`
- In line 28 and 31, Change `guess` to `int(txt.get())`
- In line 30, typo(misspelled) error change this `lbl3.confgure` to
  `lbl3.configure`
- In line 34 and 38, Move this `tk.Label` widget outside of function
  and add `lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)` too.
- In line 34 and 38, Add `configure` to `lbl.configure(text=f"Enter a number here form 1-100")`
- In line 50 comment out `#guess = int(txt.get())`. So you don't need
  this.
- As of Python 3.6, f-strings

You're ready to got.

Snippet modified to reduced code:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk

#need to count how many attempts you made
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Number guessing game")
window.geometry('350x200')

lbl = tk.Label(window, text="Enter a number here from 1-100: ")
lbl.grid(column=0,row=0)

guess_var = tk.IntVar(window)

txt = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=guess_var, bg='red')
txt= tk.Entry(window, width=10)
txt.grid(column=1,row=0)

numguess = 0
secret_num = random.randint(1, 100)


def clicked():
    global numguess
    #if guess < 0:
        #lbl2.configure(text ="Please enter a sensible number.")
    #if guess > 100:
        #lbl2.configure(text ="Please enter a sensible number.")
    if int(txt.get()) == secret_num:
        lbl2.configure(text =f"You guessed correctly.")
        lbl3.configure(text=numguess)
    elif int(txt.get()) < secret_num:
        numguess = numguess + 1
        lbl2.configure(text =f"higher!")
        lbl.configure(text=f"Enter a number here form 1-100")
    else:
        numguess = numguess + 1
        lbl2.configure(text =f"lower!")
        lbl.configure(text=f"Enter a number here form 1-100")

lbl = tk.Label(window, text=f"Enter a number here form 1-100")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

lbl2 = tk.Label(window)
lbl2.grid(column=1, row=2)

lbl3 = tk.Label(window)
lbl3.grid(column=1, row=3)

btn = tk.Button(window, text="Enter", command=clicked)
#guess = int(txt.get())

btn.grid(column=3, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]